# How to show complete list item in Autocomplete Textbox?

Tags: android

In my application I have to show all list item on clicking **Textbox**.

I have tried `AutoCompleteTextView` without entering text but its not working.

Is there any other widget in Android to achieve this situation?

Please suggest me.

Thanks,

Comment: Use [Spinner](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html) Widget in android to show the dropdown of the list item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
  android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
  android:ems="10" >

private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1); 


String[] xyzvalues= getResources().
   getStringArray(R.array.list_of_xyzvalues);
   ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
   (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,xyzvalues);
   actv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Try this working on my machine..

Answer (score 2):

```
Okay for AutoCompleteTextView, try this way :

In XML Layout:

    <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
      android:ems="10" >
In MainActivity,

    private AutoCompleteTextView actv;
    actv = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView1); 

The next thing you need to do is to specify the list of suggestion items to be displayed. You can specify the list items as a string array in java or in strings.xml. 

    String[] xyzvalues= getResources().
       getStringArray(R.array.list_of_xyzvalues);
       ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter
       (this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,xyzvalues);
       actv.setAdapter(adapter); 


Hope this helps.
```